# Set hidden variable value equal to entire HTML of table

Tags: jquery, html-table, export-to-excel

I'm trying to POST the entire HTML for a dynamic table to another page which will parse the HTML as an XLS file.  I can't seem to get the onClick jQuery correct though, as the generated .XLS file just has contains one cell that reads : `[object Object]`.

```
onsubmit='$j("#datatodisplay").val( $j("#table1") ).html()'
```

`datatodisplay` is the name/id of the hidden variable,

`table1` is the table name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `html()` inside the `val()` function:

```
onsubmit='$j("#datatodisplay").val( $j("#table1").html())'
```

Comment: That's weird... now it gives me a 500 error on SaveToExcel.asp.  :\

Comment: is this old asp or asp.net?  Could be an issue with passing HTML to the server side which then fails validation.  In ASP.NET you can explicitly allow HTML to be submitted via postback - I'm not sure if ASP has something similar.

Comment: You may need to do a html encode on the markup before saving it to the hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

look at your parentheses.

You calling `.html()` on the result of `val()`, not its argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the whole table's HTML then you will need to wrap it in another element to be able to use the `.html()` function to get the opening and closing `<table></table>` tags:

```
$('form').on('submit', function () {
    var $table = $('#table1').wrap('<div />'),
        html   = $table.parent().html();

    $table.unwrap('<div />');

    $('#datatodisplay').val(html);
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JGnh9/

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as using `.bind()`.